# Product with different VAT class depending on customer circumstances

Tags: magento-1.9, bundled-product, tax-class

There are some products in our clients site which are sometimes at standard UK vat rate of 20%, but depending on the client, and their situation they may be able to buy it at 0% VAT.

Products can only have 1 tax class assigned, so we tried making a configurable product, and 1 variation being 0% and the other at 20%, but that doesn't work due to the way Magento uses the pricing from the configurable item, not the individual products.

Instead we've opted to use a product bundle, with 2 associated products and this appears to work fine.

Is this the best option to use for this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use Customer Groups to handle this. Just set the product up in the normal way with a tax class of "Taxable Goods".

If the customer is in a certain customer group then they don't get charged VAT, otherwise they do. How you handle sorting customers into groups is up to you, you could just add a checkbox to the signup form to determine which group a customer should be in.

**To set up the Tax classes**

In *Sales > Tax > Customer Tax Classes* add a new group e.g. Ex VAT Customers.

In *Sales > Tax > Manage Tax Zones and Rates* create a new rate called TAX Exempt at 0%, you'll probably want to select the UK as well. You'll probably already have a UK rate set at 20%.

Then in *Sales > Tax > Manage Tax Rules* create a new rule selecting the following

- Customer Tax Class = Ex VAT Customers (or whatever you called it above)
- Product Tax Class = Taxable Goods
- Tax Rate = Tax Exempt (created above)

**Assigning tax rate to Customer Groups**

In *Customers > Customer Groups* create a new custom group and assign the new tax class from above (Ex VAT Customers).

Now whenever a customer in that group places a "Taxable Goods" item into their cart there will be no tax charged.

**Limited to certain products?**

If this is limited to only certain products then you'll have to create a new tax class and assign those products to it rather than to the "Taxable Goods" class. Also, when creating the rule above, change "Taxable Goods" to whatever you call the new rate new tax rate.

Comment: It's not likely that people would be repeat customers, so we'd have to pre-approve each account for the new tax class? Could they choose their own customer group from the checkout page?

Comment: Here's a plugin that allows customers to choose their own customer group at registration/checkout.
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/customer-group-at-registration.html
Note: - I've not actually used this plugin, so no idea how well it works.